# typescript filter array with array

Tags: arrays, typescript

Breaking my head over here....
I would like to filter an array with another array.

Use case, I have an array and that array can be filtered with dynamic checkboxes.

So far I have come up with the following code:

```
var filteredList = this.arrayList.filter(function(e){
           return activeCheckbuttons.filter(function(e2){
               return e2.Description != e.Description
           }).length == 0;
})
```

The above code works when clicking only one checkbox, however when clicking two checkboxes it doesn't.

Anybody?

Thanks,

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to filter `arrayList`, and return only those items whose `Description` matches any of the items in `activeCheckbuttons`. Or you want to get only those who do not match against any one?

Comment: Reading more carefully, what you are doing is filtering all elements that do not have the same description than all the items in activeCheckbuttons, so, of course, if you have two items in that array, unless they are the same item or have the same description, you'll end up with no results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need, I think, is, for each item in `arrayList`, to check if there is an item in `activeCheckbuttons` with the same description. If there is one, we add that item to the result, but, if there isn't, we ignore them:

```
const filteredList = this.arrayList.filter(item1 => 
     !!activeCheckbuttons.find(item2 => item1.Description === item2.Description)
);
```

Now, how this code works:

- With `filter` we make a check for each element in the array. If the predicate for that item returns `true`, then the elment is returned. Is not, it is skipped.
- Inside the predicate, we use the `find` method to determine whether the item we are checking exists in the `activeCheckbuttons` array (comparing their descriptions). `find` returns the first element that matches a condition, so, if it finds one, then the predicate for that item is `true`. If it does not find any, then returns `null`, which is `false`, and the item does not appear in the filtered array.

You'll see that I am also using the `!!` operator. This operator is just applying the `logical not` operator twice. Why? Just as way to cast an object to the value `true` and to cast `null` to false:

- `!!{}` -> `!(!{})` -> `!(false)` -> `true`
- `!!null` -> `!(!null)` -> `!(true)` -> `false`

This is not really necessay, but I do like to do so to  make clear in the code that I want to return `true` or `false` and not objects or null.

As stated in my comment, the problem in your code is that you are filtering the second array, removing all elements that do not have the same description as the item you are checking. Of course, if you have more than one, I suppose they're are different so the `filter` function returns at least one element, the main `filter` returns `false` and your result array is empty.

If this is not exactly how you need to filter, tell me and I'll modify the code accordingly

Comment: Hello Oscar, thanks for helping me out.
I'm not sure if I understand your answer correctly, example:
Think of a list of people and they have 3 different sexes : (M)ale, (F)emale and (U)nkown. So I have 3 checkboxes as well, when selecting M and F I want to filter out all males and females from that list. Does this make more sense?

Comment: You mean that the elements selected won't be in the results? Or that they will be? I mean, if we have `[bob, alice]` and you select `Male`, should the filter return `[bob]` or return `[alice]`

Comment: In the exmple you give, if I click male, it should return only bob, if I click Male and Female it should return Bob and Alice

Comment: Then my code is okay. Check my answer and the explanation. Of course the predicate itself (the comparation of `Description` properties) can be modified to suit your specific needs

Comment: Nice answer Oscar. Just a comment: don't you think that having to explain something is a sign that it is not making things more clear?

Comment: I find the predicate itself to be very clear, which does not mean there are people not well versed in array methods that may not understand it easily. The OP told me they weren't sure they understood, so I tried to explain better.

Comment: @OscarPaz. Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for.